# Remove placeholder attribute in search bar and update the text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**The problem**

I have a search bar with placeholder text and it should be removing the placeholder, before then adding new text to the search bar.

**What works**

The search bar initially displays placeholder text and does remove it.

The code I have is below:

```js
//On result of operation this removes the placeholder text in the search bar
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(':input').removeAttr('placeholder');
});
```

```css
.custom-search {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 2.5%;
}

.buttons .custom-search-input {
    width: 30%;
    padding-right: 15px !important; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 2vh;
}

.custom-search-button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px; 
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    line-height: 1 !important;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search-bar" class="input-group custom-search">
  <input type="text" value="" class="form-control custom-search-input" placeholder="Search here">
    <button class="btn btn-primary custom-search-botton" type="submit">Search</button>  
</div>
```

However, when I add the following, I expect it to remove the placeholder and then replace the empty text in the search bar with 'you have searched', but it instead replaces the entire search bar with the text and the search bar no longer appears...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(':input').removeAttr('placeholder');
  $("#search-bar").text('You have searched');
});
```

**What I've tried**

This other jquery script only replaces the placeholder, and again the text isn't added.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(':input').removeAttr('placeholder');
  $("#search-bar").val('You have searched');
});
```

This JS script gives the same issue as the first jquery script, it completely removes the search bar and only displays the text...

```html
document.getElementById("search-bar").innerText = "You have searched";
```

Just to reiterate, I'm not trying to replace the placeholder. I need to remove the placeholder and add text to the search bar...

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not clear what you want to achieve. `$("#search-bar").text('You have searched');` will replace everything inside the div with the text specified. Add another div if you want to have the text appear above/below/next to the search field

Comment: Sorry about that, I wanted the text to appear in the search bar. I followed your advice and added an id to the html input, and referenced that id instead of the '#search-bar' id in the js query and it now works. Thanks

Comment: You're making this way harder than it should be :-) `let $input = $('input'); $input.attr('placeholder', ''); $input.val('Added some text');`

Comment: Alternative: `$("#search-bar").find(':input').val('You have searched');`  ??